# Transferring Umbraco Site to Wordpress, keep same url/permalinks?

Tags: wordpress, url, mod-rewrite, umbraco, permalinks

We're moving a site from Umbraco to Wordpress and need to find a way to convert the URLs so they still work. The permalink of the Umbraco site is `blog/posts/2015/may/` which doesn't work with Wordpress as, although you can create custom permalinks, you can't get the month name in there, only the month number - so it would be `blog/posts/2015/05/` and not the month name *May*.

If there's not an easy way through Wordpress, how can I rewrite urls to change the month name to the month number?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to recreate the correct URLs with the following combination of tags under Permalinks > Custom structure:

```
/blog/posts/%year%/%monthname%/%postname%/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the php function `get_month_link`
And then just split it with `explode`

Example:

```
<?php $date = get_month_link('2004', '10');
 $MandY= explode(" ", $date );
 echo $MandY[0]; // October
 echo $mMandY[1]; // 2004
?>
```

Reference:
[here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_month_link)